# Calculate the average RU/s by looking at the CosmosDB Metric Logs

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-monitoring

I am trying to calculate the average of RU/s by looking at the CosmosDB Metric Logs.

```
AzureMetrics
| where MetricName == "TotalRequestUnits"
```

I cannot make sense of the following properties in `TotalRequestUnits` entries: `Total`, `Count`, `Maximum`, `Minimum`, `Average`. What is their meaning in this context? Which property describes the total of RUs beeing used at the time of logging?

Is it `Total` or `Count`?

Here is an example entry:

```
TenantId
xxx

SourceSystem
Azure

TimeGenerated [UTC]
2018-10-19T12:01:00Z

ResourceId
xxx

Resource
xxx

ResourceGroup
xxx

ResourceProvider
MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB

SubscriptionId
xxx

MetricName
TotalRequestUnits

Total
15,445

Count
6,585

Maximum
168

Minimum
0

Average
2.3454821564

TimeGrain
PT1M

UnitName
Count

Type
AzureMetrics

_ResourceId
xxx
```

The Azure Monitor Documentation is also not very clear about it: [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftdocumentdbdatabaseaccounts)

Which property am I supposed to use to calculate the average RU/s?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which property am I supposed to use to calculate the average RU/s?

As same as you,did not find explicit official document to explain what each of these metrics means.

In my opinion:

`Total` is total value of consumed RUs.

`Count` is total counts of request records.

So `Avg` = Total/Count (15445/6585) = 2.3454821564.

`Maximum` is the max consumed Rus of request records which is the opposite of `Minimum`.

And `UnitName = Count` against the Unit column in the [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftdocumentdbdatabaseaccounts).

So, if you want to calculate the avg Ru/s, please refer to the AVG in your metrics log.

Answer (score 1):

**I will try to answer my own question.** This query produces a graph that I was looking for.

```
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider contains "Document" and MetricName == "TotalRequestUnits" and ResourceGroup == "xxx"
| extend RUsPerMinute = Total / 60
| extend RequestsPerMinute = Count / 60
| project-rename MaxRURequest = Maximum
| project TimeGenerated, RUsPerMinute, RequestsPerMinute, MaxRURequest 
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

[image]

In case anyone wants to build great graphs, take a look at the documentation of the query language: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/